# Put git commit hash into paste buffer after commit

Tags: git, copy-paste

When I do `git commit` I would like for the resulting commit's hash to be put into my paste buffer. Is this possible?

Comment: Which operating system? If UNIX-based, which paste buffer? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Use a post-commit hook and run (assuming Linux here, and that the X11 paste buffer is the one you want) `git rev-parse HEAD | xsel --clipboard` at the end of it. Make sure your `.git/hooks/post-commit` is executable.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to a post-commit hook, if you don't want this to *always* happen (i.e. sometimes it's really annoying if your paste buffer gets overwritten), make an alias, e.g.:

```
[alias]
    my_commit = "sh -c 'git commit \"$@\" && git rev-parse HEAD | xsel --clipboard'"
```

Bonus: it's easy to put this in your global gitconfig to get it in all repos.